# Persistent bottom navigation bar flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

I used a bottom navigation bar in flutter using [this widget](https://pub.dev/packages/google_nav_bar),

how can I make that bottom navigation bar show on all the pages?

and can I make it appear when I choose a page from drawer??

please help me,

Comment: welcome to stackoverflow. Please, provide more details to your question to receive the best responses. Thank you for being a part of the community.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can actually achieve this with the pageview widget
https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/PageView-class.html
With this, you can have all the pages inside one class and build the bottom navigation bar underneath the pageview widget. By default the pages are swipeable but you can disable it doing

```html
Scaffold(

body:
Container( 
child: 
Column(
children: <Widget> [
PageView(
  physics:new NeverScrollableScrollPhysics())
  controller: _controller,
  children: [
    MyPage1(),
    MyPage2(),
    MyPage3(),
  ],
  ),
  googleNavBar()
]
)
);
```

Comment: ok, that's working with me, but when I open the MyPage1() the BottomNavigationBar will be shown, but when I open another page into MyPage1(), the BottomNavigationBar is disappeared!,

Answer (score -1):

May I suggest you to use flutter builtin **BottomNavigationBar** widget instead of third party widget.

Here is my code you can modify as per you requirement. Hope this will help.

```
class DashboardScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _DashboardScreenState createState() => _DashboardScreenState();
}

class _DashboardScreenState extends State<DashboardScreen> with SingleTickerProviderStateMixin {
  final _selectedItemColor = Colors.white;
  final _unselectedItemColor = Color(0xFF828282);
  final _selectedBgColor = Color(0xFF00cde7);
  final _unselectedBgColor = Colors.transparent;
  int _currentIndex = 0;

  GlobalKey<ScaffoldState> _key = GlobalKey();

  // List of body of current screen you import/create from other dart file. 
  final List<Widget> _children = [
    HomeScreen(),
    AppointmentScreen(id: 1),
    PaymentScreen(id: 1),
    ProfileScreen(id: 1)
  ];

  // List of dynamic app bar for different page. You can also import/create app bar easily
  final List<Widget> _childAppBar = [
    HomeAppBar(),
    AppointmentAppBar(),
    PaymentAppBar(),
    ProfileAppBar()
  ];

  void _onItemTapped(int index) {
    setState(() {
      _currentIndex = index;
    });
    debugPrint("Tapped item : $index");
  }

  Color _getBgColor(int index) =>
      _currentIndex == index ? _selectedBgColor : _unselectedBgColor;

  Color _getItemColor(int index) =>
      _currentIndex == index ? _selectedItemColor : _unselectedItemColor;

  Widget _buildIcon(IconData iconData, String text, int index) => Container(
    width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
    height: kBottomNavigationBarHeight,
    child: Material(
      color: _getBgColor(index),
      child: InkWell(
        child: Column(
          mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.max,
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.stretch,
          children: <Widget>[
            Container(
                child: Column(
                  children: [
                    Icon(iconData, color: _getItemColor(index)),
                    Text(text,
                        style: TextStyle(fontSize: 12, fontWeight: FontWeight.w500, fontFamily: 'Poppins', color: _getItemColor(index))),
                  ],
                ),
            ),
          ],
        ),
        onTap: () => _onItemTapped(index),  // function responsible for navigation on tap
      ),
    ),
  );

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      home: Scaffold(
        key: _key,
        appBar: _childAppBar.elementAt(_currentIndex),  // this is dynamic app bar
        body: _children.elementAt(_currentIndex),       // this is dynamic body of the current screen
        bottomNavigationBar:
        BottomNavigationBar(
          currentIndex: 0,
          type: BottomNavigationBarType.fixed,
          iconSize: 30.0,
          items: [
            BottomNavigationBarItem(
              icon: _buildIcon(Icons.home, "Home", 0), // Check this _buildIcon function above
              title: SizedBox.shrink(),
            ),
            BottomNavigationBarItem(
                icon: _buildIcon(Icons.group, "Appointment", 1),
                title: SizedBox.shrink(),
            ),
            BottomNavigationBarItem(
                icon: _buildIcon(Icons.add_circle_outline, "Make Payment", 2),
                title: SizedBox.shrink(),
            ),
            BottomNavigationBarItem(
                icon: _buildIcon( Icons.person_outline, "My Account", 3),
                title: SizedBox.shrink(),
            ),
          ]
        ),
        drawer: _currentIndex == 0 || _currentIndex == 3 ? Drawer(  // check to show drawer on particular screen
          child: ListView(
            padding: const EdgeInsets.all(0.0),
            children: <Widget>[
              UserAccountsDrawerHeader(
                  accountName: Text("Mohammad Gayasuddin"),
                  accountEmail: Text("ladla8602@gmail.com"),
                  currentAccountPicture: CircleAvatar(
                    backgroundColor: Colors.white70,
                  )),
              ListTile(
                  title: Text('Login'),
                  trailing: Icon(Icons.lock),
                  onTap: () {
                    Navigator.push(
                      context,
                      MaterialPageRoute(
                        builder: (context) => LoginScreen(),
                      ),
                    );
                  }),
              ListTile(
                  title: Text('Sign Up'),
                  trailing: Icon(Icons.add_circle_outline),
                  onTap: () {
                    Navigator.push(
                      context,
                      MaterialPageRoute(
                        builder: (context) => RegisterScreen(),
                      ),
                    );
                  })
            ],
          ),
        ) : PreferredSize(
          child: Container(),
          preferredSize: Size(0.0, 0.0),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: that is not working! if you didn't understand me, I need to keep BottomNavigationBar on all the app pages

Comment: This is not the complete code you need to write code for each pages you want to show like HomeScreen(), ProfileScreen() and import into this file.
This is the working snippet from my running project.
Note: BottomNavigationBar will be shown in all your pages that you have added in _children List.

Comment: ok, that's working with me, but when I open the HomeScreen() the BottomNavigationBar will be shown, but when I open another page into HomeScreen(), the BottomNavigationBar is disappeared!,

Comment: BottomNavigationBar will be only visible to the page that are mentioned inside _children list

Comment: You can use pageview widget inside HomeScreen body then bottom bar will be visible